# How to remove trailing CR quickly?

Tags: shell-script, debian, performance

This is my source file, it dumps a database into a JSON and worked great with Debian wheezy:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Status: 200"
echo

echo {

printf ".mode csv\nselect * from cfg;" | sqlite3 /home/ftproot/cfg/config.db | while IFS=, read col1 col2

do
if [ "$col2" = "true" -o "$col2" = "false" ]
then
  echo "\"$col1\" : $col2,"
else
  case $col2 in
    *['"']* ) col2=$(echo $col2 | sed 's/\"//g') ;;
  esac
  echo "\"$col1\" : \"$col2\","
fi
done
echo "\"ZZZZZ\" : \"\""
echo }
```

I need to update it for Debian stretch, and I get an unwanted carriage return. No problem, I fixed it and with this version I get a correct output:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Status: 200"
echo

echo {

printf ".mode csv\nselect * from cfg;" | sqlite3 /home/ftproot/cfg/config.db | while IFS=, read col1 col2

do
col2=`echo "$col2" | sed 's/.$//'`
if [ "$col2" = "true" -o "$col2" = "false" ]
then
  echo "\"$col1\" : $col2,"
else
  case $col2 in
    *['"']* ) col2=$(echo $col2 | sed 's/\"//g') ;;
  esac
  echo "\"$col1\" : \"$col2\","
fi
done
echo "\"ZZZZZ\" : \"\""
echo }
```

The problem is, that the correct version is very slow (The database is not big but I have limited hardware). The first version runs in about 300ms, the second runs in 6 seconds. How should it be changed in order to speed up the execution?

Thanks!

Comment: You can always move the first sed to before the while as a quick and dirty optimization. That way you just do it one time. `sqlite3 ... | sed 's/.$//g' | while ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You new version is calling `sed` on every line. You can likely avoid by removing the CR with just one call to `tr` in the initial command:

```
printf ".mode csv\nselect * from cfg;" | sqlite3 /home/ftproot/cfg/config.db | tr -d '\r' | while IFS=, read col1 col2
```

Answer (score 3):

The performance problem can result from the fact that you run

```
col2=`echo "$col2" | sed 's/.$//'`
```

for every line. BTW: This removes the last character of every line even if it is not a carriage return. I suggest to use `sed 's/\r$//'`

You can do this for the whole output

```
printf ".mode csv\nselect * from cfg;" | sqlite3 /home/ftproot/cfg/config.db | sed 's/\r$//' | while IFS=, read col1 col2
```

If you simply want to remove all `'\r'` and don't want to keep these characters when they may appear in the middle of the line, you can also use `tr -d '\r'` instead of `sed 's/\r$//'`.

Comment: Both solutions works, I picked the other because shorter

Comment: @michelemarcon If you like it short, I also often use `dos2unix` in lieu of using `tr` or  `sed`  expressions.